# Change the date format of the default Phone app in Micromax canvas 4

Tags: settings, call-history, micromax

In the **Phone** app (which came as as a preinstalled on my Micromax canvas 4 Device, running Android 4.2), the date format used (in the call logs for example to show history of calls placed/received) is USA-Style like **mm-dd-yyyy.**, like 08/09/2015 (for 9th-August-2015).

I checked the phone app's settings but could not find a way to change it to **dd-mm-yyyy.**, like 09/08/2015 (for 9th-August-2015).

Of course, I can certainly install another 3rd party app which can give an option to customize data format, but just want to check if it is possible in the preinstalled system app.

Anyone knows how to change date format from mm-dd-yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy?

Comment: Could you upload the APK of your phone app? My device doesn't have such issue, so I can't try anything as of now, other than to Google.

Comment: "My device doesn't have such issue" Which device it is and how can u change the date format in your device? I will try to upload my apk too, but if u can help with above query, i can give it  a try too

Answer (score 1):

Actually mm-dd-yyyy date format is used in American English(USA-style) and dd-mm-yyyy is used in British English(UK-Style) So to change date format in your device simply change language option in your device from US-English to UK-English.

**Settings->Language & Input -> Language -> English(UK)**.

I hope it would help.